# JavaFX MediaPlayer lags

Tags: javafx, media-player

When i listen a music by MediaPlayer and do some actions, music lags. Some actions are for example writing code, searching in google, etc. Try this

### ***Main***

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Example e = new Example();
    e.start();
}
}
```

### Example

```
public class Example extends Thread {
@Override
public void run() {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media("http://cdndl.zaycev.net/play/1435335/8AXraqSa7-NfuEyu2cxQh27JI8BUZIt7wgWuJQJRZatUrSYkwtWXT931qxVSZvBSlhH_M09RfScoMwGZDHZeU_an_KsTccAzSHCVwGREBZ3pUCNm-dNBK1c2kzB5vbfhyH2cA_9CL86EG2VV0li8THuxDdM?dlKind=play&format=json"));
    mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
        synchronized (Example.this) {
            Example.this.notify();
        }
    });

    mediaPlayer.play();

    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

And what is important i have good internet speed. What is my problem?

Comment: Probably not related, but you shouldn't be running that in a background thread. What does "do some actions" mean?

Comment: @James_D it means for example writing code in IDE, searching in browser and any other actions.

Comment: @James_D i tried play in main JavaFX thread and it still lags.

Comment: @James_D actually I've started playing my MediaPlayer/AudioClips in Executor threads because the VM hangs onto JFXMediaThreads until the end of time increasing your Heap usage. If you play them in an Executor thread they will be disposed immediately when finished.

Comment: @ProstoCoder what exactly do you mean by "music lags"?

Comment: @PhilipVaughn sound can be looped for a few milliseconds, that is, the same place in the song is forgiven several time

Comment: @ProstoCoder the song plays the same part several times? I've actually NEVER had that happen before using MediaPlayer and I use it for games which have a lot of action going on.

Comment: Ok, so here's something you should always do with MediaPlayer. You should ALWAYS attach it to a MediaView attached to your pane. If your program loses focus for whatever reason MediaPlayer will sometimes do weird things when not in a MediaView.

Comment: @PhilipVaughn ok, i will try this with mediaview

Comment: @PhilipVaughn it did not help D:

Comment: @ProstoCoder You need a window to attach the MediaView to. It will operate the exact same as before if the MediaView isn't attached to a Pane attached to the window.

Comment: @PhilipVaughn i did this

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code sample. In the window you could just put a label with "Playing Music" lolz

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Media pick = new Media("put.mp3"); // replace this with your own audio file
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(pick);

        // Add a mediaView, to display the media. Its necessary !
        // This mediaView is added to a Pane
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);

        // Add to scene
        Group root = new Group(mediaView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setTitle("Media Player");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // Play the media once the stage is shown
        player.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Still continues to hang.

Comment: Ok, try replacing the URL you want with an actual music file on your computer and see if it still hangs.

Comment: Yep that's really weird. May be a computer issue? I'm at a loss because I can basically do anything on my computer using just the code above without any hang.

Comment: What JDK version do you use?

Comment: 8 or 9 (either one but 9 forces you to change all your code if you want to use modules so sometimes I use 8)